# Know the flow before an event on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to know which path flow one user has used before converting in paying users.

Actually I'm simply calling (i.e to track when user buy some package):

```
ga('send', { hitType: 'event', eventCategory: 'package', eventAction: 'bought'});
```

Now my doubt is how can I know which path flow the user has done before this event?

i.e > visited homepage > visited pricing page > bought package.

At the moment I'm using section Audience > User report with a custom segment with the event to track buy package.

Is this the right way to do what I want to achieve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while this is a good question it is not a programming question. Possibly a better place for reporting question might be webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok moved! You can close if you want!